# Tkinter Scrollbar position, yview_moveto() seems not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Consider the following example:

```
from tkinter import *

startingWin = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(startingWin, height=600)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="nsew")
canvasFrame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=canvasFrame, anchor='nw')

for i in range(70):
    element = Button(canvasFrame, text='Button %s ' % i)
    element.grid(row=i, column=0)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(startingWin, orient=VERTICAL)
yscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

canvas.yview_moveto(0.5)

canvasFrame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

startingWin.mainloop()
```

**Expected output:** ***Scrollbar in the middle.***

However, I get the Scrollbar ***always on the top***, ***regardless*** of the value I give to `yview_moveto()` like the following:

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `canvas.yview_moveto(0.5)` until after the `scrollregion` has been defined.